# Notation related to probability spaces

Tags: probability, notation

Let $A$ and $B$ be events in the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathcal{P})$. How would I write that

> events $A$ and $B$ both occur

and

> event $A$ occurs with probability $0.5$ and the event $B$ does not occur

and

> neither of the events occurs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An event $A$ (a subset of $\Omega$ that is also a member of $\mathcal F$) is said to occur if and only if the outcome of the experiment is an element
that belongs to $A$. The outcome $\omega$ of the experiment is always *one* element of the sample space $\Omega$, but the occurrence of this outcome $\omega$ leads to
*many* events occurring because $\omega$ is a member of numerous subsets
of $\Omega$ that are in $\mathcal F$. In particular, regardless of what
$\omega$ is, *one and only one* of the events $A$ and $A^c$ must occur
because $\omega$ necessarily belongs to exactly one of $A$ and $A^c$; it
cannot belong to both, and it cannot be excluded from both. 
If $\mathcal F$ is a finite collection of subsets (there must be $2^n$
of them for some integer $n$), then *half* the events occur and *half*
don't, regardless of what $\omega$ is. In some sense, this is also true when $\mathcal F$ has infinitely many subsets: there is a one-to-one correspondence $A \leftrightarrow A^c$ between those events that occur and those that don't.  $\Omega$ *always* occurs and
so is called the *sure* or *certain* event, while its complement
$\emptyset$ never occurs ans so is called the *impossible* event
(also the *null* event by some, but there are many, including myself,
who deprecate this usage).

With that as prologue, if you are told that events $A$ and $B$ *both*
have occurred, then the outcome $\omega$ must be a member of both
$A$ and $B$, right? What is the notation for the set of elements that
are members of both $A$ and $B$?

Comment: So $\omega\in A\cap B$ for both occuring at the same time? Thanks for the thorough answer, it was helpful.